# Adding two different Objects by overloading operator+ C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure out how to add a private member from Object A, to a private member from Object B.

Both Cat and Dog Class's inheriate from the base class Animal. I have a thrid class 'MyClass', that I want to inheriate the private members of the Cat and Dog class. So in MyClass, I have a friend function to overload the + operator. THe friend function is defined as follows:

```
MyClass operator+(const Dog &dObj, const Cat &cObj);
```

I want to access dObj.age and cObj.age within the above function, invoke by this statement in main:

```
mObj = dObj + cObj;
```

Here is the entire source for a complete reference into the class objects:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vld.h>

   using namespace std;

   class Animal
   {
   public :
    Animal() {};
    virtual void eat()  = 0 {};
    virtual void walk() = 0 {};
   };

   class Dog : public Animal
   {
   public :
    Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age);
    Dog() : name(NULL), gender(NULL), age(0) {};
    virtual ~Dog();
    void eat();
    void bark();
    void walk();

   private :
    char * name;
    char * gender;
    int age;
   };

   class Cat : public Animal
   {
   public :
    Cat(const char * name, const char * gender, int age);
    Cat() : name(NULL), gender(NULL), age(0) {};
    virtual ~Cat();
    void eat();
    void meow();
    void walk();
   private :
    char * name;
    char * gender;
    int age;
   };

   class MyClass : private Cat, private Dog
   {
   public :
    MyClass() : action(NULL) {};
    void setInstance(Animal &newInstance);
    void doSomething();

    friend MyClass operator+(const Dog &dObj, const Cat &cObj);

   private :
    Animal * action;
   };

   Cat::Cat(const char * name, const char * gender, int age) : 
     name(new char[strlen(name)+1]), gender(new char[strlen(gender)+1]), age(age)
   {
    if (name)
    {
     size_t length = strlen(name) +1;
     strcpy_s(this->name, length, name);
    }
    else name = NULL;
    if (gender)
    {
     size_t length = strlen(gender) +1;
     strcpy_s(this->gender, length, gender);
    }
    else gender = NULL;
    if (age)
    {
     this->age = age;
    }
   }
   Cat::~Cat()
   {
    delete name;
    delete gender;
    age = 0;
   }
   void Cat::walk()
   {
    cout << name << " is walking now.. " << endl;
   }
   void Cat::eat()
   {
    cout << name << " is eating now.. " << endl;
   }
   void Cat::meow()
   {
    cout << name << " says meow.. " << endl;
   }
   Dog::Dog(const char * name, const char * gender, int age) : 
     name(new char[strlen(name)+1]), gender(new char[strlen(gender)+1]), age(age)
   {
    if (name)
    {
     size_t length = strlen(name) +1;
     strcpy_s(this->name, length, name);
    }
    else name = NULL;
    if (gender)
    {
     size_t length = strlen(gender) +1;
     strcpy_s(this->gender, length, gender);
    }
    else gender = NULL;
    if (age)
    {
     this->age = age;
    }
   }
   Dog::~Dog()
   {
    delete name;
    delete gender;
    age = 0;
   }
   void Dog::eat()
   {
    cout << name << " is eating now.. " << endl;
   }
   void Dog::bark()
   {
    cout << name << " says woof.. " << endl;
   }
   void Dog::walk()
   {
    cout << name << " is walking now.." << endl;
   }


   void MyClass::setInstance(Animal &newInstance)
   {
    action = &newInstance;
   }
   void MyClass::doSomething()
   {
    action->walk();
    action->eat();
   }


   MyClass operator+(const Dog &dObj, const Cat &cObj)
   {
    MyClass A;
    //dObj.age;
    //cObj.age;
    return A; 
   }

   int main()
   {
    MyClass mObj;
    Dog dObj("B", "Male", 4);
    Cat cObj("C", "Female", 5);

    mObj.setInstance(dObj); // set the instance specific to the object.
    mObj.doSomething();  // something happens based on which object is passed in
    dObj.bark();

    mObj.setInstance(cObj);
    mObj.doSomething();
    cObj.meow();

    mObj = dObj + cObj;

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: I'm confused ... what is the question exactly?

Comment: do you have some objection to std::string?

Comment: Read up on the `protected` access qualifier keyword. Otherwise, this example is nonsensically contrived. Why should `operator+` be in a class *derived* from its operands?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a private member of Dog, then your operator has to be a friend of Dog, not just a friend of some derived class of Dog.

Comment: In other words: you can touch the privates of your friends, but you can't touch the privates of your friends parents.

Comment: +1: *Just because you trust your friends into your house, does not mean that you father will trust them with the safe combination*

Comment: Or put another way - friendship is not transitive or inherited. God that makes me hot!

Answer (score 0):

If you add `friend MyClass operator+(const Dog &dObj, const Cat &cObj);` to the definition of class Cat and class Dog, then the function will have access to `dObj.age` and `cObj.age`.

Alternatively, you could add `friend MyClass;` to the definitions of class Cat and class Dog, but then all of MyClass's functions have access to all of Cat and Dog's internals.

Alternatively alternatively, you could make `age` protected rather than private.